# How do I get rid of broad-leaved dock in my strawberry bed?

Tags: weed-control, strawberries

I have a strawberry bed that the strawberry plants like to grow in, but [broad-leaved dock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex_obtusifolius) (also known as Bitter Dock, Bluntleaf Dock, Dock Leaf or Butter Dock) seems to like it better. They are trying to take over and I don't know what to do. How do I get rid of it without damaging the strawberries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q.** Do you keep the strawberry bed “overly” moist? What size is the strawberry bed?

> **A.** It is a dry area about 6' by 20' (ca. 1.8m × 6m).

Seeing as the bed is “dry” I’m not quite sure what to suggest, as Dock tends to prefer moist conditions, but if it’s thriving in dry conditions…

Maybe regular, shallow hoeing will help you get it under control (eventually).

Though the following information doesn’t help you with your existing strawberry bed, it may prove somewhat helpful to keep in mind for the future—I was reminded this past weekend, most commercial strawberry growers cover their beds in black plastic (helps keep unwanted plants under control), then cut holes in the plastic to plant their strawberry plants.